# Detect more than one touch on HTML5 Canvas

Tags: html5-canvas

I am trying to detect if there is more than one touch on the canvas.The following code gives an error, when there is only one touch:

```
function get_touch(event){
    cor_x = event.touches[1].pageX;
    cor_y = event.touches[1].pageY;

}
```

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question. Are you just looking to count the touches?

Comment: yes, I want number of touches.

Comment: So how have you tried getting the length of the touches list?

Comment: Yes, the length is 1 even after multitouch. Moreover, the coordinates of the first touch become constant to the values just before the second touch.

Comment: Then the problem isn't in the code you show and you should add this information to the question...

Comment: Just in case: IE uses a different approach (Pointer/MSPointer) than Firefox/Chrome for detecting multi-touches.

Answer (score 0):

For iterating over all the touches:

```
for (var x=0;x<event.touches.length;x++) {
  cor_x = event.touches[x].pageX;
  cor_y = event.touches[x].pageY;
}
```